# Creating dynamic ul li for a carousel with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a carousel with a ul li dynamically using the following code:

```
        var arrEanSample = [];
        var arrPathSample = [];
        var arrValSample = [];

        var thecookie = $.cookie("sample");
        var cookies = thecookie.split("|");

        cookies.forEach(function(item){

            var barcode= item.split('~')[0];
            var value = item.split('~')[1];
            var path = item.split('~')[2];

            arrEanSample.push(barcode);
            arrPathSample.push(path);
            arrValSample.push(value);
        });

        var output='<ul class="slides">';
       for(var i = 0; i < arrEanSample.length; i++)
        {
        output+= '<li ean="' + arrEanSample[i] + '">\
                    <img src="' + arrPathSample[i] + '" alt="pix" draggable="false">\
                    <a imgpath="' + arrPathSample[i] + '"  value="' + arrValSample[i] +'" ean="' + arrEanSample[i] +'" class="unselectsample-thumb" data-statsaction="coupon-basket-remove" data-statscategory="coupon-buttons" title="Remove" href="#">\
                        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fonticon fonticon-close-neg">\
                            <span class="sr-only">Remove</span>\
                        </i>\
                    </a>\
               </li>';
        }
        output+='</ul>';
        $('.flexslider').empty().append(output);
```

The code above is generating a html that looks like this(unnecessary codes removed):

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li ean="9904153320507">
    <li ean="9904153300509">
    <li ean="9904153441004">
    <li ean="9911199120503">
    <li ean="9911199071003">
  </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is, i have to group all the LI's in sets of 10, whereby one li would countain a ul with 10 such LI's. As follows:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <div class="list-samples">
        <ul class="reset">
          <li> li number 1 </li> 
          <li> li number 2 </li> 
          <li> li number 3</li> 
          <li> li number 4</li> 
          <li> li number 5</li> 
          <li> li number 6</li> 
          <li> li number 7</li> 
          <li> li number 8</li> 
          <li> li number 9</li> 
          <li> li number 10</li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
         <div class="list-samples">
            <ul class="reset">
              <li> li number 11 </li>
              <li> the list goes on - as sets of 10's ... </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me on achieving the above code with my starting JS

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = '<ul class="slides"><li><div class="list-samples"><ul class="reset">';
for(var i = 0; i < arrEanSample.length; i++){
if(i % 10 == 0 && i != 0){
    output += '</ul></div></li><li><div class="list-samples"><ul class="reset">';
}
output+= '<li ean="' + arrEanSample[i] + '">\
            <img src="' + arrPathSample[i] + '" alt="pix" draggable="false">\
            <a imgpath="' + arrPathSample[i] + '"  value="' + arrValSample[i] +'" ean="' + arrEanSample[i] +'" class="unselectsample-thumb" data-statsaction="coupon-basket-remove" data-statscategory="coupon-buttons" title="Remove" href="#">\
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fonticon fonticon-close-neg">\
                    <span class="sr-only">Remove</span>\
                </i>\
            </a>\
       </li>';
}
}    
output += '</ul></div></li></ul>';
```

Comment: my div ul.reset is remaining empty

Comment: + i have an extra <div class="flexslider">

Comment: This generates the entire dom object. Just remove the extra div in the first output line and the closeing div in the last. The extra output line has an ul at the end that also needs to get the right class. I missed that.
I've updated the code.

Comment: the code generated seems ok.. but my final li in ul.reset remains empty :(

Comment: actually its okay.. my mistake